# Date picker iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, datepicker

I am really new to iOS development, and I know this will be a silly question but I need to do something like this: I have a button in my view, when I press it , then a date picker should appear. When a date is selected, date picker should disappear and the selected date should be shown in my UILabel.

How can I do this? I am using Xcode 5. I want to do this for iOS 7.

Please give me tutorial links, code samples, steps to follow or anything which I need to do this. Please help me.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found this, maybe it will help :)

http://masteringios.com/blog/2013/10/31/ios-7-in-line-uidatepicker/

//edit: I skimmed through the tutorial, this is not a good example.

Use `UIDatePicker` is better.

Answer (score 0):

Add this code in your click event :

```
UIDatePicker *myPicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:pickerFrame];
[myPicker addTarget:self action:@selector(pickerChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
[self.view addSubview:myPicker];
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: i tried this.. but i want to do something like this : when user select a date , the date picker should hide and the date should apear in a text field